# Why String Array null check not working?

Tags: java, android, encoding

I am reading a text file and checking for the null column, but null check isn't working and I am getting ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception.

I am reading a text file like this

```
fstream17 = new FileInputStream(
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/InputFiles"
                            + "/XYZ.TXT");
            in17 = new DataInputStream(fstream17);
            buffreader17 = new BufferedReader(new UnicodeReader(in17));

            while ((strRead = buffreader17.readLine()) != null) {
                splitarray = strRead.split("\t");
                Log.d("Split array", ""+splitarray[0]/*+""+splitarray[11]*/);

                if(splitarray[8] == null || splitarray[8].length() == 0) //Checking for null coloumn 
                {
                    Log.d("Null", "Null");
                }
```

And my UnicodeReader class looks like this.

```
public class UnicodeReader extends Reader
{
    private static final int BOM_MAX_SIZE = 4;

    private InputStreamReader delegate;

    public UnicodeReader(InputStream in) throws IOException {
        init(in, null);
    }

private void init(InputStream in, String defaultEnc) throws IOException {
        String encoding;
        byte bom[] = new byte[BOM_MAX_SIZE];
        int n, unread;
        PushbackInputStream internalIn = new PushbackInputStream(in, BOM_MAX_SIZE);
        n = internalIn.read(bom, 0, bom.length);

        if ((bom[0] == (byte) 0xEF) && (bom[1] == (byte) 0xBB) && (bom[2] == (byte) 0xBF)) {
            encoding = "UTF-8";
            unread = n - 3;
        }
        else
            if ((bom[0] == (byte) 0xFE) && (bom[1] == (byte) 0xFF)) {
                encoding = "UTF-16BE";
                unread = n - 2;
            }
            else
                if ((bom[0] == (byte) 0xFF) && (bom[1] == (byte) 0xFE)) {
                    encoding = "UTF-16LE";
                    unread = n - 2;
                }
                else
                    if ((bom[0] == (byte) 0x00) && (bom[1] == (byte) 0x00) && (bom[2] == (byte) 0xFE) && (bom[3] == (byte) 0xFF)) {
                        encoding = "UTF-32BE";
                        unread = n - 4;
                    }
                    else
                        if ((bom[0] == (byte) 0xFF) && (bom[1] == (byte) 0xFE) && (bom[2] == (byte) 0x00) && (bom[3] == (byte) 0x00)) {
                            encoding = "UTF-32LE";
                            unread = n - 4;
                        }
                        else {
                            // Unicode BOM mark not found, unread all bytes
                            encoding = defaultEnc;
                            unread = n;
                        }

        if (unread > 0)
            internalIn.unread(bom, (n - unread), unread);
        else
            if (unread < -1)
                internalIn.unread(bom, 0, 0);

        // Use BOM or default encoding
        if (encoding == null) {
            delegate = new InputStreamReader(internalIn);
        }
        else {
            delegate = new InputStreamReader(internalIn, encoding);
        }
    }
```

But this check is not working now, what I am getting now is ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception for this.

Comment: You should check the length of `splitarray` before checking null on `splitarray[8]`.

Comment: The value splitarray[8] does not exist

Comment: @ wns349: yes, I am checking that too.

Comment: Your code should look like splitarray.length >=8 and not splitarray[8].length ==0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
if(splitarray == null || splitarray.length >= 8) //Checking for null coloumn 
{  
  Log.d("Null", "Null"); 
}
```

Or to be on the safer side, when you use split the length of the array is defined based on your string.**Hence you do not have to do a null check against the element**. Just get the length of the array using the `.length` and you are good to go.